# Primefaces Calendar Inline Mode Wrong Size

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, primefaces

Primefaces Calender with inline mode shows in bugged way:

[image: primefaces Calendar]

Code:
xHTML

```
<p:tab title="Logs">
<p:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2" styleClass="logsGrid">
<p:accordionPanel id="accordionLogs" styleClass="logsAccordion">
<p:tab title="Log1"></p:tab>
<p:tab title="Log2"></p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
<p:calendar value="#{dateBean.date}" mode="inline" styleClass="logsCalendar">
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{dateBean.handleDateSelect}" update=":growlMain" />
</p:calendar>
</p:panelGrid>
</p:tab>
```

class:

```
package com.swql.sprint;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

@ManagedBean
public class DateBean {

    private Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void handleDateSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        Date date = (Date) event.getObject();
        FacesMessage msg = null;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Date Picked", format.format(date));
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }

}
```

How to fix this issue?

€dit:

**Already figured out the reason:
The p:panelGrid somehow resizes the content of the calendar.
Maybe a fix would be to put the calendar into some other container.
Will try and report.**

€dit2:

**Putting the Calendar into a panel doesn't fix the issue.**

Comment: Has been fixed in Primefaces 4.0.5 and 3.5.21
https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for now is to use the html gridPanels:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2" styleClass="logsGrid">
<p:calendar value="#{dateBean.date}" mode="inline" styleClass="logsCalendar">
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{dateBean.handleDateSelect}" update=":growlMain" />
</p:calendar>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand here what Design you are trying to create bur i used this code...

```
<p:tab title="Logs">

<p:accordionPanel id="accordionLogs" styleClass="logsAccordion">
<p:tab title="Log1"></p:tab>
<p:tab title="Log2"></p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
<p:calendar   mode="inline" styleClass="logsCalendar">
<p:ajax event="dateSelect"    />
</p:calendar>

</p:tab>
```

It work fine for me

Comment: you have to put it into a panelGrid to reproduce